Remove MFi hearing device
I attempted to pair Oticon Real hearing aids to my M2 MacMini/Sequoia.  The pairing appears to have stopped in an uncertain state.  Only the right aid is shown in the MFi Hearing device list.  The Connect button is not active and the Available Devices spinner never stops.  Right clicking shows no menu.  There appears to be no way to remove the one aid in the list or add another.  How can I get back to baseline with no entries in the MFi Hearing Device list?
